# Equivalent of git checkout ours/theirs for submodules

Tags: git, git-merge, git-submodules

When resolving a conflict in a file I can

```
git checkout --ours filename
```

and then commit the file. This will resolve the conflict. However,

```
git checkout --ours submodule
```

doesn't seem to work. The reference commit for the submodule doesn't change.

What would be the equivalent of `git checkout --ours filename` when resolving conflicts in submodule references?

Comment: This was probably an issue with git 1.7.1. Among the tree alternatives (`-2`, `--ours` and `HEAD`) only `git checkout HEAD submodule` does what it supposed to do. Maybe all three would work on a newer version of git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Considering your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41151216/6309), you can try a checkout of one of the three stages for your submodule:

```
git checkout -1 -- submodule # common ancestor
git checkout -2 -- submodule # source
git checkout -3 -- submodule # destination or MERGE_HEAD
```

Once a gitlink of a submodule has been changed, don't forget a `git submodule update`, to refresh its content.

The OP [Amiramix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745250/amiramix) refers to this [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/In-a-git-merge-conflict-how-do-I-tell-git-that-for-files-X-Y-and-Z-I-want-it-to-screw-the-local-changes-and-simply-overwrite-with-the-version-being-pulled-in), where [Berk D. Demir](https://www.quora.com/profile/Berk-D.-Demir), Production Engineer at Facebook, adds:

```
git checkout -1 file
```

> ...will checkout the file from the ancestor of two branches.
>   This is neither "ours" nor "theirs". It's the version of the file right before these two branches diverged. Quite handy.
>
> As you can guess, parameter `-2` is for the version from HEAD and `-3` is version from `MERGE_HEAD` accordingly.
>
> Another way to reach these files through all other git commands is to use the symbolic-refs of commits.
>   `git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- file` gives the same effect with `--theirs` or `-3`.
>
> Another handy syntax when dealing with merge conflicts is the colon-stage-colon prefix to path.  `git show :3:file` will show the file (not the diff) from `MERGE_HEAD`.
>
> A tiny cheat sheet:

```
-1 == $(git merge-base HEAD MERGE_HEAD)
-2 == --ours == HEAD
-3 == --theirs == MERGE_HEAD
```

Comment: So, would `git checkout -2 -- submodule` be equivalent of "ours" and `git checkout -3 -- submodule` be equivalent of "theirs" of a normal file merge? Also, I am only merging, I don't need the submodule to be checked out or updated to that specific commit. Can I ignore `git submodule update` and just commit merged changes?

Comment: @Amiramix yes to both questions.

Comment: OK, thanks, will test that later and accept if it works.

Comment: I am testing but this doesn't seem to work.`git checkout -1 -- submodule` returns `unknown switch \`1'`. `git checkout -2` and `git checkout -3` doesn't return any error but `git diff` still shows three commits in the unmerged path (theirs, ours, and checked out locally). I am using git 1.7.1 (stuck with Centos6), could this be the reason?

Comment: @Amiramix possibly. I haven't used an 1.7 in years. I would recommend compiling a 2.11 on Centos6 (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source, dependencies listed in http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/git.html)

Comment: I just found and I am testing this answer https://www.quora.com/In-a-git-merge-conflict-how-do-I-tell-git-that-for-files-X-Y-and-Z-I-want-it-to-screw-the-local-changes-and-simply-overwrite-with-the-version-being-pulled-in and looks like the equivalent `git checkout HEAD submodule` and `git checkout MERGE_HEAD submodule` works in 1.7.1. Can you please add it to the answer and I will accept.