# Three commit references when merging submodules

Tags: git, git-merge, git-submodules

I am merging a branch in a project that uses git submodules. Usually when there is a conflict there are two sets of changes, theirs and ours. Resolving the conflicts is about merging these two into one. But I noticed that for git submodules the diff shows a third value:

```
diff --cc my_submodule
index dd7404e,e6753b1..0000000
--- a/my_submodule
+++ b/my_submodule
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,1 @@@
- Subproject commit dd7404e5f35ee0b0064f0d6ed8201cc39d6ed6b2
 -Subproject commit e6753b1142cf0350608720ff23f7ecf51b813cd9
++Subproject commit 3b4e75fbb7c55cf21e19509bbbbfabfa1fc10630
```

What do the "- ", " -" and "++' mean?

Note that it's possible that the submodule version actually checked out in the repository before the merge was neither theirs nor ours, would that explain the three hashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means the submodule **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (the [special entry in the index of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) was changed *both* in source and destination.
(See [`git diff` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))

`++` means one line that was added does not appear in either branch1 or branch2

From [Git Tools - Advanced Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging):

You have three SHA1 because in a conflict, Git stores all of these versions in the index under “stages” which each have numbers associated with them.

- Stage 1 is the common ancestor,
- stage 2 is your version and
- stage 3 is from the `MERGE_HEAD`, the version you’re merging in (“theirs”).

The **[combined diff format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format)** section has all the details:

> When shown by `git diff-files -c` (combined diff of merged files), it compares the two unresolved merge parents with the working tree file
>
> I.e.
>
> - `file1` is stage 2 aka "our version",
> - `file2` is stage 3 aka "their version".
>
> A `-` character in the column `N` means that the line appears in `fileN` but it does not appear in the result.
>   A `+` character in the column `N` means that the line appears in the result, and `fileN` does not have that line".

In your case:

- A `-` in the first column means `file1`, meaning stage 2, meaning "ours" version.
- A `-` in the second column mean `file2`, meaning stage 3, meaning "theirs".
- A '`++`' means an addition which was not in `file1` or `2` (each time when compared with the common ancestor from stage 1)

Comment: What does it mean that it changed in source? Comparing to what? Local changes? In this particular example which SHA1 is ours, with "- " or " -"?

Comment: @Amiramix comparing to the common ancestor.

Comment: @Amiramix See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format:  When shown by `git diff-files -c` (combined diff of merged files), it compares the two unresolved merge parents with the working tree file (i.e. file1 is stage 2 aka "our version", file2 is stage 3 aka "their version").

Comment: OK, but when git shows the two deletions and one addition it doesn't say which deletion version is coming from which stage difference. It only shows "- " and " -". Would it consistently associate "- " with the difference between stage 1 and stage 3 for example (or between stage 1 and stage 2)?

Comment: @Amiramix yes, the output remains consistent for any merge.

Comment: Sure, but which is which? I mean, which one of the "- " and " -" is for which difference (stage 1 to 2 and 1 to 3)?

Comment: @Amiramix from the doc: "A `-` character in the column N means that the line appears in `fileN` but it does not appear in the result. A `+` character in the column `N` means that the line appears in the result, and `fileN` does not have that line": so a `-` in the first column means file1, meaning stage 2, meaning "ours" version. A `-` in the second column mean file2, meaning stage 3, meaning "theirs". A '`++`' means an addition which was not in file1 or 2 (each time when compared with the common ancestor from stage 1)

Comment: Great, that's going to be a handy reference.